# How does Java know the types of objects and data when reading them back from a file

Tags: java, input

Hi I am new to Java and learning, I have searched for an answer to this question here and googled it, looked at the Java Doc but cant seem to find a clear explanation on exactly this topic.

When wrapping streams and Serializable objects, writing a mix of objects, data, primitives to a file, then reading them back again the data, objects, primitives must be read back exactly in same sequence as it was written. If there is mismatch in type or wrong sequence you get EOFException.

How does Java know the types of objects and data when reading back the file? I can only conclude this is stored in the file, or maybe the FileDescriptor? But there is nothing about this in the Java docs? or is there?

EDIT: I have tested this (Java 8) and I get a EOFException if I have the wrong sequence, and I get the Exception just at the start of reading the file.

EDIT2: Sorry I did not post the code, kind of lost it because I did many different stream writing and reading and got EOFException on several occasions when starting to read the file, correcting the type errors took away the exception. Code as follows, had to recreate from memory.

```
try (DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dataFile)))) {

        for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
            dataOut.writeDouble(prices[i]);
            dataOut.write(numbers[i]);
            dataOut.writeUTF(desc[i]);
        }

 try (DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(dataFile)));) {
        double price;
        int number;
        String description;
        int c = 0;
        while (true) {
            price = dataIn.readDouble();
            number = dataIn.readInt();
            description = dataIn.readUTF();
            System.out.println(price + " " + number + " " + description);
```

I have omitted some code but the core elements are there, so the readInt method produces a EOFException, (write method used, not writeInt). If i correct the error (change to writeInt) everything runs fine. However if I swap places between price and number when reading there was no error and printed out rubbish, but still completed normally.

```
while (true) {
            description = dataIn.readUTF();
            price = dataIn.readDouble();
            number = dataIn.readInt();
```

But if I move the readUTF when reading the file I yet again get EOFException.

Comment: If you've got some test code, you should show it. I've produced test code which *doesn't* show an exception. I'm sure once you produce your code, I can explain the exception you're seeing, but I can't do so without knowing what I'm trying to explain.

Comment: So your code could easily have been trying to use `readUTF` for example - if the bytes of data present suggested that the string was very long, and there wasn't enough data in the stream. Again, it's not that the data is tagged with "this is a string", "this is an int" - it's just that if you try to read bad data, sometimes that *will* cause it to try to read off the end of the stream...

Comment: I've added an example of this sort of problem causing an `EOFException` - but it's not that Java "knows" the data types that have been read; it's just trying to read the data you've asked it to.

Comment: With your update, it's basically as I described - you were calling `readUTF` when the data at the stream at that point wasn't appropriate. So it was almost certainly reading a huge value for the length, and reading off the end of the stream. My answer provides a complete example of that situation and explains it. Again, this is *not* a matter of Java "knowing" that it wasn't written by `writeUTF`. Is there anything you still don't understand?

Comment: Thanks Jon, I read your example and compared it with my test and I think I understand the issue now. I did a similar test with Object streaming and is was like you said. Thanks again.

Comment: What's with all the EDIT EDIT EDITs?  Are you aware that we keep a detailed edit history of your question?  No need to call out specific edits; they're all there: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28164672/revisions.  You're better off maintaining the question as a coherent whole, rather than trying to turn it into a forum post.

Answer (score 51):

> If there is mismatch in type or wrong sequence you get EOFException.

No, that's simply not true - at least not in the general case. You'll get an `EOFException` if you reach the end of the data too early. If you just read the data with the wrong methods, but still read the same amount of data (e.g. calling `readInt` twice instead of `readLong` once) you'll get useless data, but no exception. (There are exemptions to this - if you use `readUTF` you'll get an exception if the data isn't valid modified UTF-8 for example. Or `readUTF` *could* throw an `EOFException` if the length prefix says that the string is longer than the data in the stream - again, that's a matter of reading past the end of the stream.)

Here's a complete example:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        byte[] data;
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos)) {
                dos.writeLong(123456789012345L);
            }
            data = baos.toByteArray();
        }

        try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(data)) {
            try (DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bais)) {
                System.out.println(dis.readInt()); // 28744
                System.out.println(dis.readInt()); // -2045911175
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that when using `ObjectOutputStream`, when you call `writeObject` that *does* write the type name as part of the data, so that when you call `readObject` it knows what kind of object to create. However, the primitive reading/writing methods (such as the ones used above) still don't leave any indication of the type of data. Changing `DataObjectStream`/`DataInputStream` to `ObjectOutputStream`/`ObjectInputStream` in the above code doesn't change the result.

If you call `readObject`, and the stream is placed at the start of object data, it still won't throw `EOFException` - it will just read the correct kind of object, and if you cast it to the wrong type you'll get a `ClassCastException`. (There's no way of saying "I expect to read a `Foo` now.") If you call `readObject` and the stream *isn't* placed at the start of object data, then any number of odd things might happen, based on what data *is* present there.

You would only get an `EOFException` if you tried to read past the end of the data, however you did so - e.g. writing a `long` and then reading *three* `int` values.

As an example of how `readUTF` could cause an `EOFException`, consider this code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                byte[] data;
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos)) {
                dos.writeShort(10000);
                for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                    dos.write(0);
                }
            }
            data = baos.toByteArray();
        }

        try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(data)) {
            try (DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bais)) {
                System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We start off writing the `short` value 10000, then we write 500 other bytes. When we call `readUTF`, that will read the value of 10000, and then expect to be able to read 10000 more bytes, because that's the format `readUTF` expects (length, data). *That* will fail with an `EOFException` because there isn't enough data. If you change `writeShort(10000)` to `writeShort(100)` then the exception goes away - even though you're still not matching writes with reads.

Comment: Sorry, Jon, it is true, see my answer.

Comment: @EJP: No, only for `readObject` and `writeObject`. The above code works just as well for `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`. For the primitive methods (`readInt` etc) there is *no* tagging.

Comment: No. There is tagging for all primitive types too. Try it. I did.

Comment: @EJP: As I've said several times, I *have* tried it. Unlike you, I've shown the code which *does* try it. I can't try *your* code because you haven't shown it, but you can very easily try my code, because it's in my answer. Changing `Data*` for `Object*` doesn't change the result. Please try it now, and then explain why it doesn't throw an exception - instead working precisely as documented.